# Error installing Pandas library with pyhton3.9

Tags: pandas, python-3.9

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [12 lines of output]
+ meson setup C:\Users\t720880\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff3v9v5i\pandas_aa581445d51c4dcbada38ff1234efd29 C:\Users\t720880\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff3v9v5i\pandas_aa581445d51c4dcbada38ff1234efd29.mesonpy-woh3qziv\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\t720880\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff3v9v5i\pandas_aa581445d51c4dcbada38ff1234efd29.mesonpy-woh3qziv\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.1
Source dir: C:\Users\t720880\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff3v9v5i\pandas_aa581445d51c4dcbada38ff1234efd29
Build dir: C:\Users\t720880\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff3v9v5i\pandas_aa581445d51c4dcbada38ff1234efd29.mesonpy-woh3qziv\build
Build type: native build
Project name: pandas
Project version: 2.1.1

```
  ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

  A full log can be found at C:\Users\t720880\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ff3v9v5i\pandas_aa581445d51c4dcbada38ff1234efd29\.mesonpy-woh3qziv\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

DOES ANYONE KNOW HOW TO RESOLVE THIS ERROR ?

Error installing Pandas library with pyhton3.9

Comment: Welcome to SO. I encourgae you to make your question easier to read, by futher formating it. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for guidance.